# How do I translate the QGraphicView to the position where I doulbleclicked?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I'm trying to translate the position of the `QGraphicView` to the position where I doubleclicked on. I tried the function `translate` and `centerOn` but none of them work. So I'm gessing I'm doing something wrong.

For a simple example, if I use this code:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys



class SurfViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.setFixedWidth(600)
        self.setFixedHeight(600)
        photo = PhotoViewer()
        self.setCentralWidget(photo)


class PhotoViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.UpdateScene()
        self.scene.update()

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        position = QPointF(event.pos())
        position = self.mapToScene(position.x(),position.y())
        print(position)
        print(position.isNull())
        if not position.isNull():
            #self.centerOn(position)
            print(position.x(),position.y())
            self.centerOn(position.x(),position.y())
            self.scene.update()
            self.update()

    def UpdateScene(self,):
        xsize=100
        ysize=100
        newitem = QGraphicsEllipseItem(0-xsize/2., 0-ysize/2., xsize, ysize)
        newitem.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.black, style = Qt.SolidPattern))
        self.scene.addItem(newitem)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('window')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

I plot a circle in the middle of the view. when I double click on the view, I enter to the `mouseDoubleClickEvent` fonction and I get the coordinate of the mouse during the click with `QPointF(event.pos())`. Hopefully, this is working.

Now I would like the position I got be the center of the view. So I tried to translate the view with both `translate` or `centerOn` but nothing happend. I also try to map the corrdinate to the scene but that didn't help neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`centerOn()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#centerOn) only makes the position visible, if it is already visible it will not make any change. The solution is to move the [`sceneRect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop) centering it on the point that is pressed:

```
def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
    p = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
    r = self.sceneRect()
    r.moveCenter(p)
    self.setSceneRect(r)
```

Comment: Ho nice. Works perfectly.